# Toast won't go away

Tags: java, android, mobile

I wrote code that I found to get a marker from an array value. I put a toast in the `else` condition. When I try to run it, the toast didn't do away. If I press the search button directly it will go to the first value of the array.

Here is the code:

```
btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(int i=0; i < address.length; i++) {
                if (address[i].toLowerCase().contains(editsearch.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase())){
                    marker.remove();
                    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i])).title(address[i]).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
                    CameraPosition campos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i]))
                            .zoom(18)
                            .build();
                    CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(campos);
                    myMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
                    break;
                } 
            }
Toast.makeText(Myactivity.this, "Error", duration).show();
        }
    });
```

I tried to get wrong result so i can see toast message, but when I input the right value it is still on the `else` condition.

I want the toast message to show when I input the wrong value. The value is for example an array of addresses which are "Paris" "Rome" "Alberta" "Zurich". When I try to input Sydney it should show like the address is not available.

Comment: Because your else case is in for loop put it out side of it and try..

Comment: so i should make another statement for `false` conditon ?

Comment: what is that address variable contains?

Comment: address is also an array, well I've put `return` statement on toast message, the message is go away but if i put the right value it will be on else condition which is keep telling me `error` message

Comment: try my answer below, it will count the errors and show only one toast at the end of the loop

Comment: It will be wrong to use `break` or `return` statements because when the else part is called, the if statement will stop.

Comment: `if i put the right value it will be on else condition which is keep telling me error message`  SO you are giving wrong input then.. try with `address.size()` in for loop instead of `address.length`

Comment: i can't change to `address.length`

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you are toasting every time you iterate in that for loop. When the condition is false, you get in the else part every time you iterate. To solve this you just need to get that `Toast` out from the `for loop`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so what you suggest me to do? should i make another `if condition`? because that `else` part is to show what is wrong if i didn't input right value

Comment: The if statement is called every time you iterate, so even if your the condition is once true, the else part is called for every itereation. You need to change the logic of your code. You need to meet a condition and then iterate accordingly.

Comment: To stop the Tost from showing every time you iterate, a simple way will be to remove the else part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the For-Loop is hitting that condition many times and making the toast appear to be static, when in fact it's just a bunch of them called simultaneously. Android throws theses toasts into a queue and displays them one by one in the order they are received. Try something like this, which will count the errors and display one single toast at the end of the loop:

```
btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int errorcount = 0;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for(int i=0; i < address.length; i++) {
            if (address[i].toLowerCase().contains(editsearch.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase())){
                marker.remove();
                myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i])).title(address[i]).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
                CameraPosition campos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i]))
                        .zoom(18)
                        .build();
                CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(campos);
                myMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
                break;
            } else {
                errorcount++;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(Myactivity.this, "Finished with " + errorcount + " errors.", duration).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes it does show if any error value i put and it dissapear, but when i try to input right value the toast keep showing, so i want toast message show when i input the wrong value, the value is for example array from address which is `"Paris" "Rome" "Alberta" "Zurich"` so when i try to input Sydney it should be show like `address is not available`

Answer (score 0):

Add boolean flag to check whether address was found or not

```
btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {  
        boolean found = true;
        for(int i=0; i < address.length; i++) {
            if (address[i].toLowerCase().contains(editsearch.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase())){  
                found = true;
                marker.remove();
                myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i])).title(address[i]).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
                CameraPosition campos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(lat[i],lon[i]))
                        .zoom(18)
                        .build();
                CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(campos);
                myMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
                break;
            } else {
                found = false;
            }


        }
       if(!found) Toast.makeText(Myactivity.this, "Error", duration).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: but it still have an error message although i put right value

Comment: are you sure that you are getting the correct string from edit text? please check that. put a log statement to check the value of edit text

Comment: yes i'm sure, first declaration wa `EditText editsearch;` second `editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editsearch);'

Comment: in onClick just check what are you getting.

Comment: i have edited my post now the error is always come if i input both value, keep show me error, i just want when the value i input is wrong then show a message

Comment: my answer will do the same

Comment: I've tried it but it show both value, i use that value to search marker of maps activity. so when i type right `address` value it's still show me toast message

Comment: i guess this `editsearch.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()` is not giving correct output

Comment: which one i should change?

Comment: first, put a log statement in onClick method to check what is the result of `editsearch.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()` this will ensure that you are getting correct input from edit text